# Shell script to backup sql metadat recursively

Tags: sql, shell, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am writing a shell script to automate the sql metadata backup everyday.

Please help me out with the command to take sql backup of 1 day instead of all databases and append it to last taken backup.

```
FILE= mysql_metadata_backup_$( date '+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S' ).sql
mysqldump -u userID --all-databases > ${FILE}
<tar ....missing command>
```

For Storing the password in `.my.cnf` file in order to avoid mentioning it in the mysqldump tool.

Comment: What do you mean, "*take sql backup of 1 day*?"

Comment: I meant If I have taken the backup of all the sql databases yesterday. today I need to take backup for only 1 day ie, from yesterday to today and append it to the previous backed up file.

Comment: Maybe you can use the update_time of each table in the information_schema to identify which tables have been updated since the last dump `select pseudo, amount FROM table1 ORDER BY amount desc limit 1;`

However, I'm not sure that running this type of backup is a good idea, as restoring the data might not be trivial.

You would also have to expend on this idea for stored routines, views, etc.

Comment: I think you are correct. I want to take recursive backup each day and delete the other backup keeping last 3 backups. any help on this methodology?